# How to find an object without an arrayList

Tags: java, class, object, search

I'm currently working on a program where i have a large amount of objects (all the elements from the periodic table) and it would be a huge pain to have to create a List for over 100 objects. Is there any way i can declare and instantiate all the objects one time and have a method read the class they exist in? For example if a user inputs "He" i can find the corresponding object that holds the elementSymbol "He"? I would have to be able to check each object using the getSymbol method which returns its symbol and then compare it to the input. After that i plan on using other fields assigned to the object like it's molar mass for calculations but that isn't going to be an issue. If there is another way to effectively do this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you want to use ArrayList? To me this sounds like the perfect use case for it.

Comment: @moscar Exactly what I thought too. Simply add the element classes to an array list and use lambda to select what is required based on the element's id.

Comment: This guy also did it with enums: https://gist.github.com/felixdivo/11159677. This is what @Vovka suggested in his answer below. An enum is an elegant solution for this requirement given the constant nature of the periodic table.

Comment: @ManoDestra thank you so much that was exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

You should store everything into a `Map` with the `elementSymbol` as key and your `object` as value, then you will be able to access to your object by calling `map.get(elementSymbol)`.

More details about the class `Map` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

Answer (score 3):

As you have constant number of objects, it is better to manage them with enum:

```
public enum Elements {
    ag(10), //10 here is the molarMass constructor parameter
    he(20);

    //constructor if needed
    Elements(int molarMass) {
        this.molarMass = molarMass;
    }

    //extra fields
    final private int molarMass;
}
```

get:

```
Elements.valueOf("he")
```

Comment: How would i able able to search this class or check every enum against an input? I'm not very familiar with enums

Comment: Element he=Element.valueOf("he"); /* "he" its input string */
int m=he.getMolarMass();

Answer (score 1):

you can use a `hashmap` for this.

```
HashMap<String,PeriodObject> peridicTable = new   HashMap<String,PeriodObject>();
periodictable.add("he",object);
periodicTableobject = periodictable.get("he");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're averse to using an ArrayList, it's a perfectly valid solution to your requirement. I think use of an Enum is the better solution given the constant nature of the periodic table, but I'm adding this List answer, utilizing the streams API for completeness.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.run();
    }

    private void run() {
        List<Element> elements = new ArrayList<>();
        Element oxygen = new Element("O", "Oxygen");
        Element carbon = new Element("C", "Carbon");
        Element hydrogen = new Element("H", "Hydrogen");
        Element helium = new Element("He", "Helium");
        elements.add(oxygen);
        elements.add(carbon);
        elements.add(hydrogen);
        elements.add(helium);

        System.out.println("All Elements:");
        for (Element element : elements) {
            System.out.println("\t" + element);
        }

        System.out.println();

        Element oxy = elements.stream().filter(e -> e.getId().equals("He")).findFirst().get();
        System.out.println("Specific Element: " + oxy);
    }

    private class Element {
        private final String id;
        private final String name;

        public Element(String id, String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return this.id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return this.getName() + " [" + this.getId() + "]";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It was tedious enough to have to manually type each element and I figured there had to be a more efficient way of being able to access them. I really didn't want to have to go back and do list.add() over 100 times. I'm sure there is a better way to do that with a list but using an enum to hold them worked much better